# How to compare entries in the same JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have this JSONObject below containing multiple entries of orders

```
   {"ORDER_1": {"FNAME" : "JOHN","LNAME" : "B","ORDER_ID" : "D123"},
    "ORDER_2": {"FNAME" : "LAURA","LNAME" : "S","ORDER_ID" : "D456"},
    "ORDER_3": {"FNAME" : "JACK","LNAME" : "H","ORDER_ID" : "D123"}}
```

And here is the code where I dynamically collected the customers information and put them into a hashset of JSONObject

```
    Set<JSONObject> customerCollection = new HashSet<JSONObject>();
    Iterator<String> keys = (Iterator<String>) customerOrders.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        JSONObject obj = customerOrders.getJSONObject(key);

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray customerList = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject customer = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject customerObj = new JSONObject();

        customer.put("FNAME", obj.optString("FNAME"));
        customer.put("LNAME", obj.optString("LNAME"));
        customerObj.put("customer", customer);
        customerList.add(customerObj);
        result.put("customers", customerList);

        customerCollection.add(result);
    }
```

Based on the above code, the output is formatted as followed:

```
[{"customers": [{"name": {"fname": "JOHN","lname": "B"}}]},
 {"customers": [{"name": {"fname": "LAURA","lname": "S"}}]},
 {"customers": [{"name": {"fname": "JACK","lname": "H"}}]}]
```

Now there is a requirement to group customers that share the same ORDER_ID.  And this is where I struggle a little bit.  How can I compare entries of the same JSONObject and group them together based on the ORDER_ID key value?  So the final output should be like this (noticed the customer JOHN and JACK are now in the same JSONArray because they share the same ORDER_ID)

```
[
    {
     "customers": [{"name": {"fname": "JOHN","lname": "B"}},
                   {"name": {"fname": "JACK","lname": "H"}}
                  ]
    },
    {"customers": [{"name": {"fname": "LAURA","lname": "S"}}
]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, shouldn't your initial JSON input would have double-quotes around the ORDER-1, ORDER-2 and ORDER-3 values?

And what is the purpose of ORDER-1 ORDER-2 ORDER-3?  Why wouldn't you simply use:

{ "orders" : [
                       {"FNAME" : "JOHN","LNAME" : "B","ORDER_ID" : "D123"},
                       {"FNAME" : "LAURA","LNAME" : "S","ORDER_ID" : "D456"},
                       {"FNAME" : "JACK","LNAME" : "H","ORDER_ID" : "D123"}
                  ]
}

Comment: You can parse Json to Map (may be using JsonPath) and work out on Map to group them. After that, you can convert back that to Json.

Comment: Also, your expected output doesn't really make sense because it doesn't associate each customers array with any order.  Instead of "customers", I would think you'd just use the ORDER_ID value so you have a correlation between the order and the array of customers for that order.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the initial JSON input with the correct double quote.  As for my expected output, this is the format and I can't change it.  The goal here is to just group customer names together based on the ORDER_ID.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic is that you are using a single loop and saving the customer for each customer entry instead of once per order.

For this to work, create a map that uses the ORDER_ID as the key for each entry and has an array of customers as its value.

Then you can iterate over that map's keyset and create the "customers" object from the array value for each key.

I realize that stackoverflow would like me to actually code the answer and post it, but I don't think that is productive (for me).